# Publish app on docker when save it

Tags: docker, deployment

I am developing a solution and it is mandatory to use docker for it. The problem is that everytime I change something in the project, I have to use docker cp to copy all the application folder to the container in order to test it.

This is a painful task and is not feasible taking in consideration that it is a very time-consuming task.
My question is: Is there a way to save my application and automatically my application be published in the container without the necessity of use docker cp command?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read up on using Docker Data Volumes - here is an [article on using docker data volumes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-docker-data-volumes-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you mount an external volume where you send your code to.
An external volume is a directory from your main OS that is mounted in a directory of your choice inside the container.
To use a volume use the -v flag in the docker run command.

Answer (score 0):

Docker comes with Dockerfile because it is/must be easy to build a new version. Get used to things similar to `docker build -t myuser:mysoft:3.23 .` when buiding version 3.23 of your software.

Answer (score 0):

Development on docker can be a bit of a curve if you don't know the tools. 
What you likely want to use is volumes instead of copying the file on the docker built image. Volumes map a path on your file system to be accessed from the docker image. Meaning any changes happening to your files are also updated on docker.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Now the issue with your reloading your application code can have different solutions based on your use case.

For node you could use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) for example or autoreload for python